# How can I log all properties of useReducer state consistently?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

This will have something to so with async but I can't get to the bottom of it.

Problem: when I log my global state object to console, it is not returning all the properties. Despite the fact that the missing property can be logged to console independently.

When I log `state.workflow` (the overall object that stores the global state) I get:

```
{
    "workflow_id": "", // Never updates
    "workflow": [...]  // Always updates
}
```

But if I separately log (`state.workflow_id`) it gives me the value.

My reducer:

```js
export default function workflowReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_WORKFLOW_ID':
      return action.payload;
    case 'SET_WORKFLOW_NAME':
      return action.payload;
    case 'ASSIGN_WORKFLOW':
      return action.payload;
    case 'ADD_NODE':
      return {workflow: [...state.workflow, action.payload]};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My context (the dispatches run on init):

```js
export const WorkflowProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workflowReducer, initialState);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized) return;
    getStoredCanvas().then((response) => {
      setInitialized(true);
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_WORKFLOW_ID',
        payload: {
          ...initialState,
          workflow_id: response.data.workflow_id
            ? response.data.workflow_id
            : JSON.stringify(mintGuid()),
        },
      });
      dispatch({
        type: 'ASSIGN_WORKFLOW',
        payload: {
          ...initialState,
          workflow: response?.data.elements,
        },
      });
    });
  }, [dispatch, initialized]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {initialized && (
        <WorkflowContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</WorkflowContext.Provider>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

My state:

```js
const initialState = {
  workflow_id: '',
  workflow_name: undefined,
  workflow: [],
};
```

My logging method:

```js
const {state} = useContext(WorkflowContext);
const sendRequest = useCallback( () => {
    if (isSending) return;
    setIsSending(true);
    console.group('%c Data to [Workflow] EP ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(state);
    console.groupEnd();
    if (isMounted.current) setIsSending(false);
  }, [isSending, state]);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why is `sendRequest` using `async`? I dont see any promise handling being done.

Comment: Unrelated functionality, irrelevant to question. Need it for when it is making an API request (not shown). Could be a log without async.

Comment: You start the question by stating you think it has something to do with async, but then you omit some async code? Ok.

Comment: I mean that console logs are synchronous whereas  I believe (not sure) the reducer is updated async. Have updated.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps some other hapless soul. The issue arose from my seeking to update the two properties independently of one another, in two `dispatch` methods rather than a single `dispatch` covering both properties. Thus

The context and initializers:

```js
export const WorkflowProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workflowReducer, initialState);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized) return;
    getStoredCanvas().then((response) => {
      setInitialized(true);
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_PROPERTY',
        payload: {
          ...initialState,
          workflow: response?.data.workflow,
          workflow_id: response?.data.workflow_id || mintGuid(),
        },
      });
    });
  }, [dispatch, initialized]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {initialized && (
        <WorkflowContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</WorkflowContext.Provider>
      )}
      {/* TODO : Add error handling */}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default WorkflowProvider;
```

The reducer:

```js
export default function workflowReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_EDGE':
      return action.payload;
    case 'SET_PROPERTY':
      return action.payload;
    case 'ADD_NODE':
      return {
        ...state,
        workflow: [...state.workflow, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```